# Azure NodeJS Functions and Service Bus, DeadLetter message

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-webjobssdk

Is it possible to dispose a message to the dead letter queue in a NodeJS function triggered by a service bus message from a topic subscription? It appears to be possible for C# functions, but I need the same functionality in a NodeJS function. [Azure WebJobs SDK Service Bus DeadLetter queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371091/azure-webjobs-sdk-service-bus-deadletter-queue)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no function we can use to dispose a message to the dead letter queue for Node.js. See [missing implementation of service bus message deadletter function #2019](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/2019). It may be helpful to ask for this feature by providing feedback to Azure team [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus).